# Servlet program not running properly

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am running one small servlet program but it is not giving expected output.

Servletfile.java

```
public class Servletfile extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/ html");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    String abc = request.getParameter("name");
    out.print("name="+abc);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<Form action= "welcome" method="get">
Enter Name :<input type = "text" name="name"><br>
<input type = "Submit" value= "login">
</Form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Practice</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>Servletfile</display-name>
<servlet-name>Servletfile</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>code.Servletfile</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servletfile</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Servletfile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

On executing the code, it's displaying index.html page but if I enter any name as an input then it's giving 404- page not found error. If I run servlet program individually, it's giving name=null as an output. Can you please suggest me something on this.

Comment: Please also post your `web.xml` file.  This is critical for us to be able to help you.

Comment: It looks like your form is not hitting the servlet, which isn't surprising given that your action is just plain "welcome", but the web.xml file will tell all.

Comment: I have added web.xml file, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `index.html` file to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<Form action= "Servletfile" method="get">
Enter Name :<input type = "text" name="name"><br>
<input type = "Submit" value= "login">
</Form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the form will map to your Servletfile `Servlet`.  The reason you were seeing `null` when you navigated to `http://localhost:8080/Servletfile` directly is that you never set the request parameter `name`.

Answer (score 0):

call action using `<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Servletfile` sometimes container not able to find your servlet that's why he showing you `404`.

Comment: I am sorry but I am totally new to this , can you please tell me exactly where I need to enter this line?? in doGet method??